# Freestyle render - Problems getting it right

Tags: rendering, freestyle, svg

I am trying to get the same result as:

[image]

From Render docs, [Freestyle SVG Exporter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/addons/render/render_freestyle_svg.html).

I have tried working with freestyle edge marks, but it does not get the desired result.

I have tried the different settings, but it I cant get the result.

Can anyone help me with the render settings?

Comment: have you checked this Q? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77647/dashed-lines-made-with-freestyle-are-rendering-inconsistently?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! I have checked that Question. I have tried using freestyle edge marking, but it wont get the same result as the above picture.

Comment: Maybe [edit] the question to add some details of what you have tried? Questions that show some effort get better responses.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the question a bit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get topographical contour lines like shown in manual? Analogous to Rhino3D functionality?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175417/how-to-get-topographical-contour-lines-like-shown-in-manual-analogous-to-rhino3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm very curious to see a better solution since I'm not very experienced with Blender myself, but perhaps this would work for you:

- create a plane an add an **Array** modifier, with Constant Offset in the Z axis. The more duplicates you create the more lines you'll have in your final render.
- select the object to be rendered and add a **Boolean** modifier.

  - Operation: Intersect
  - Object: plane
- hide the array for rendering

Repeat with any other objects to create the horizontal lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this got me much closer!!!

Comment: No worries. If you want to learn more about how the site works check the [tour], [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the super tips from Luciano, and that got me much closer. Now I think it's just me not getting the settings right:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks good! Try the Boolean:Intersect on a more complex mesh, I had some issues with it (I hope you don't) but didn't spend time trying to fix.

Comment: Did you ever got this figured out? I want to achieve similar result as well!