# How to get topographical contour lines like shown in manual? Analogous to Rhino3D functionality?

Tags: rendering, freestyle, svg

The [Freestyle SVG Exporter page](http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/render/freestyle/export_svg.html) in the manual shows this image:
[image: svg_manual_image]
but doesn't really have any indication of how to achieve this contour line look...

I did some more digging around and found [an article from 6 year ago](https://blenderyard.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/contour-lines-as-in-maps/#comments) with a similar image, that had a very similar picture and provided a script, which I've yet to try (haven't messed with scripts in blender yet...):
[image: similar image]

Is there a more "official" way of achieving this? I know e.g. Rhino3D has [contour line command](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOSwAwi8if4) so I'm wondering if blender has anything similar?

edit: I want to render the scene as an svg, should have specified. I got the script to work, but it's destructive... it operates on the mesh directly unfortunately. If anyone can find a way around this would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to export it as a svg or just render the lines ?

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/114345/29586

Comment: @Gorgious want to render as SVG... should have specified

Comment: I suggest ask a new question on this link this one

Comment: It took me a lot of effort, but I've got a separate solution here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304713/how-can-i-highlight-the-hard-edges-on-a-very-large-10-km-model/306561#306561

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple node setup that uses the separated Z texture coordinates and modulo to drive a repeating color ramp.

- Use the green cursor on the ramp to change thickness of lines.
- Use the Z Scale to adjust line space
- For the ground, same texture but using the X texture coordinate component.

[image]

Comment: thank you! This does answer the question as it was posted. Though I left out an important detail, the fact that I wanted the lines to render as an SVG. My fault, so I'll mark this as correct in a few days if no one else answers.