# Create SVG "Scan" lines in freestyle / Replicating documented effect

Tags: rendering, edges, freestyle, svg

I am observing the [documentation page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/freestyle/export_svg.html) for the freestyle SVG exporter, and would like to know how to reproduce the effect demonstrated in the header image, shown below. I am specifically interested in the effect demonstrated on the Suzanne model, not necessarily the background.
[image: images]

I am frankly lost as to where to even begin, considering the fact that the model's edges do not follow this consistent pattern, and thus I cannot use edge-marking.

I'm fairly new to freestyle, and so
any help would be appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: Here is the same question but the answer works with a shader only: [How to get topographical contour lines like shown in manual? Analogous to Rhino3D functionality?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/175417/107598)